# Explorer hangs when renaming a folder

Tags: networking, windows-10, performance, windows-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2

One PC (Windows 10 Pro version 1607.14393.321) is having a problem whereby renaming a folder that is located on a specific server (Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials version 6.3.9600) causes Explorer to hang for ~60 seconds.

Notable points:

1. This problem occurs consistently when using drive letters and UNC paths to the affected server.
2. This problem occurs consistently regardless of user account / local user profile.
3. This problem does not occur when using the affected PC to rename files located on the affected server.
4. This problem does not occur when using the affected PC to rename folders located on the internal HDD.
5. This problem does not occur when using the affected PC to rename folders located on a different server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard version 6.1.7604 SP1) on the same LAN.
6. This problem does not occur when using any other PCs (same LAN, same OS, same antivirus, same paths, etc) to rename folders on the affected server.
7. This problem does not occur when using the affected server to rename folders in the same UNC paths.
8. The affected PC has a 1 Gbps connection to the affected server.
9. The affected PC resolves the affected server's hostname instantly.
10. The affected PC pings the affected server with 1ms latency.
11. The affected PC has no problems according to command `sfc /scannow`(`Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`).

**Update 2016/10/19 16:23:**

Further notable points:

12. This problem **does** occur when using any PCs to rename folders on the affected server.
13. This problem does not occur when using the affected PC to rename folders located in a UNC path using the affected server's IP address, rather than the hostname.
14. This problem does occur when using the affected PC to create and rename folders located on the affected server with the correct entries in the hosts file.
15. This problem does not occur when using the affected PC's Command Prompt to create and rename folders located in a UNC path using the affected server's hostname.

**Update 2016/10/19 16:35:**

This seems to be a problem with DNS hostnames and Explorer in Windows 10 version 1607.14393.321. The above and some other points substantiate this conclusion.

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like a credentials or permissions issue. If another user name on the network (or Administrator) logs onto the affected local PC, rather than the normal user, does the issue occur? I realize you state "This problem occurs consistently regardless of local user profile," but I'm unsure if another login was tested.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The rename does complete successfully after the hang. Yes, we tried using a different AD user account and, therefore, local user profile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that I hadn't tried was using (1) the affected PCs, (2) Explorer, (3) a UNC path containing the FQDN, and (4) the affected server. I wasn't surprised that the problem recurred but I was surprised that it generated an error:

> "Rename Folder
>
> An unexpected error is keeping you from renaming the folder. If you
>   continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search
>   for help with this problem.
>
> Error 0x8007003B: An unexpected network error occurred."

This allowed me to discover the Microsoft TechNet article "[Problem creating/renaming a folder on a network share with Win10 Anniversary Update (Error 0x8007003B)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b72c763e-d029-4e65-a2dc-885a5aabf643/problem-creatingrenaming-a-folder-on-a-network-share-with-win10-anniversary-update-error?forum=win10itpronetworking)" which states:

1. This is a known problem with Windows 10 version 1607 (Anniversary update) and Windows Server 2012 R2.
2. The workaround is to disable the Windows service `WSearch` / `Windows Search` on the server.

I have confirmed that the workaround works.

Hopefully, Microsoft will release a proper solution soon (or test their updates properly in the first place).

Comment: this is also the official solution from MS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3198614

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue as well for many months. Microsoft has a preview [update](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=3216755) released in January to fix this issue.

Source: [Network Defend blog](https://networkdefend.blogspot.com/2016/09/fix-windows-10-error-0x8007003b-when.html)